# getExternalFilesDir is undefined in custom preference

Tags: android, android-preferences, bitmapfactory

I'm creating a custom preference `<com.myproject.CustomPreference android:layout="@layout/preferences_main" />`where I want to show the username, the phone number and the profile pic (in a circle which doesn't matter yet). I managed to get the username and phone number from the preferences with a CustomPreference.class extending Preference but I don't get the path to the profile pic because `getExternalFilesDir`is undefined for this class.
Here's my code:

```
public class CustomPreference extends Preference {
    private TextView tvusername, tvphonenumber;
    private ImageView profilepic_profile;

public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.preferences_main);
}

@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    tvusername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvusername);
    tvphonenumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvphonenumber);
    profilepic_profile = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.profilepic_profile);

    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences();

    // entering preference username in text view
    String username = prefs.getString("username", null);
    tvusername.setText(username);

    // entering preference phonenumber in text view
    String phonenumber = prefs.getString("phonenumber", null);
    tvphonenumber.setText(phonenumber);

    // Show currently saved profile pic in imageview

    String fname = "profile.png";
    Bitmap photo2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(null)
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/images/" + fname);
    if (photo2 != null) {
        GraphicsUtil graphicUtil2 = new GraphicsUtil();
        profilepic_profile.setImageBitmap(graphicUtil2.getCircleBitmap(
                photo2, 16));
    } else {
        // profilepic_profile.setBackground(profile_pic_big);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getExternalFilesDir` is a method of `Context` class.

So create a global `Context` in your class `mContext` and in your constructor do

```
public CustomPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
  super(context, attrs);
  mContext = context
  this.setWidgetLayoutResource(R.layout.preferences_main);
}
```

and then you can use `mContext` to call `getExternalFilesDir`

```
mContext.getExternalFilesDir()
```

OR

you can call

```
getContext().getExternalFilesDir()
```

Comment: So easy and I spent some time without any success - thanks a lot.

Comment: @Apoorv possible edit.  Don't save the context it probably will cause a problem when the os does cleanup because maybe something is linked to it.  Instead save the result from getExternalFilesDir()

Answer (score 2):

`getExternalFilesDir()` is a method on `Context`. You are passed a `Context` in your `CustomPreference`, and it inherits a `getContext()` method from the `Preference` base class.